# Subject returning undefined in constructor

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, angular2-services

I'm using a Subject to communicate if a user is authenticated or not. The problem is, when I subscribe to the subject in a component when I reload, the subject returns undefined.

Here is my implementation, this method checks if user data is stored in local storage. If they are stored in local storage, the Subject should be set to true.

user.service.ts

```
public auth_status:Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();

getCurrentUser(): User {
    let storage =  localStorage.getItem('current_user');

    if (storage) {
        return Json.parse(storage);
    } else {
        return null
    }
};

getUserAuth() {
    if (this.getCurrentUser() != null) {
        this.auth_status.next(true);
        console.log(this.auth_status);
    } else {
        this.auth_status.next(false);
        console.log(this.auth_status);
    }
    return this.auth_status;
}
```

navbar.component.ts

```
  constructor(private _userService: UserService) {
    this._userService.getUserAuth().subscribe(data => this.auth_status = data);
  }
```

this.auth_status toggles an *ngIf in my navbar that shows a sign in or sign out button

I've tried calling the method before subscribing to it too but that doesn't seem to work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The events are emitted before the subject is returned, therefore when `subscribe()` is called in the constructor, the events are already gone.

You can use `BehaviorSubject` to prevent that like

```
public auth_status:Subject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(null);
```

A `BehaviorSubject` emits the last event to new subscribers immediately after one subscribes.

Comment: Oh man, I feel dumb ahah! Thank you Günter! I'll accept the answer once the time limit is gone. Thanks again

Comment: No need to feel dumb :D We've all been there

Comment: You can explain why "The events are emitted before the subject is returned" if the only place he called the getUserAuth function is in the component?

Comment: `getUserAuth()` emits the events, then returns `this.auth_status;` At this point the events are already emitted. Then in the constructor `subscribe` is called.

Comment: But the only thing that emits the event is when calling the   this._userService.getUserAuth()  function.

Comment: The BehaviorSubject needs initial value so you need to update the answer